# What Does the Quota "App Config Service Config App Call Count" Refer in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have apparently maxed out the 10,000 request daily limit to "App Config Service Config App Call Count" on my python Google App Engine App, which appears to be blocking any further attempts to upload versions or edit my app (the real reason this question is being asked). I have no idea how this could be considering that there are only 18 items in the admin logs for the last 24 hours (either new versions or deleted versions). Additionally this quota is not documented at all in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas. So how do I find out what on Earth is actually going on with this quota without springing for $150 support per month?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to the App Engine mailing list, where the team is more likely to read it (plus it's got nothing to do with programming...)

Comment: Would love to, where/what is the App Engine Mailing list? As far as I knew Google delegated bronze app engine support to stack overflow - https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/3420040#bronze_details

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine

Comment: Well I posted this thing there the following day and I don't think it was even approved to be viewed. So yay, no support.